# Material UI classes For React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Like Bootstrap we know about names of all available classes like

```
<div className="container">
   </div>
```

I got a headache while finding a similar classes documentation for React.Being a beginner sorry for that.

Comment: React doesn't have default classes... the classes you pass on `className` will become what in the DOM are classes. This question is basically asking for "where's the documentation of all available HTML classes" - There is none. It depends on the CSS lib you are using

Comment: mentioned i need classes name because in documentation they are very few

Comment: *classes documentation for React* - so is this about Material UI or React in general? In React, components are primarily used to style the layout, not classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) library, it doesn't work with classes like Bootstrap, they offer their own components to use.